# Регулярное выражение для поиска слов, состоящих целиком из строчных букв

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Мне нужна помощь в составлении регулярного выражения. Мне нужен такой запрос.
Найти все слова,которые не имеют в начале, в середине и в конце заглавных букв, то есть слово должно быть полностью со строчными буквами.
Пример кода, который я пытался реализовать:

```
import re
pattern = r"\b[^A-Z]\w[^A-Z]\w+\b"
result = re.findall(pattern, 'Tort tOrt tort tOrt')
print(result)
# должен быть tort, но выводит ['tOrt', ' tort', 'tOrt']
```

Но пока выводит все слова, который Не имеют в начале заглавных букв. Что мне нужно дописать в такое регулярное выражение, чтобы оно выполняло данную задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = r"\b[a-z]+\b"  # больше одной строчной буквы английского алфавита 
result = re.findall(pattern, "tort cake cAke Tort tOrt torT TORT")
print(result)
```

Если слова будут только на английском, то этот код работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Если вы работаете не только с ASCII, лучше всего установить [библиотеку PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), введя в консоли `pip install regex`, и затем использовать следующий код:

```py
import regex
text = '...'
print( regex.findall(r'\b\p{Ll}+\b', text) )
print( regex.findall(r'\b[[:lower:]]+\b', text) )
```

где

- `\b` - граница слова
- `[[:lower:]]+` / `\p{Ll}+` - одна более букв в нижнем регистре
- `\b` - граница слова.

[Пример кода](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqsktaJEwVZBPQQkVOIPIkCsC4su7LvYcLFJ4WLThXkwBlhEnaugKDOvRAOiXy8tMy8lMSdHo0g9JimmoNonp1Y7JkldRwFkrqaCJm7F0dFWOfnlqUVWsbEoOv7/BwA):

```py
import regex
text = 'Tort tOrt tort Торт тОрт торт'
print( regex.findall(r'\b\p{Ll}+\b', text) )       # => ['tort', 'торт']
print( regex.findall(r'\b[[:lower:]]+\b', text) )  # => ['tort', 'торт']
```

**Если нет возможности установить PyPi `regex`**, используйте

```py
import re, sys
pLl = "".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).islower()])
text = 'Tort tOrt tort Торт тОрт торт'
print( re.findall(fr'\b[{pLl}]+\b', text) ) # => ['tort', 'торт']
```

См. [пример кода](https://tio.run/##NY5NCsIwFIT3PcWjmyRYsnHtDQQ37tou@pPaJ2lS0ogtIkgP4sKDeIb2RDFR3AzD8PEx/WRbrbbOYddrY8GIBIZpiPq9hB3EMT9rVDStWkORQaMNIKACU6iToB7kXTFeFFa6FgywgR/IcZD6KgxlOYusGK13kWPw20OI0JbX8l4f6wzrvDz/5buQqDeoLPVneIOqLqSkjSFZmd78rXu@yUqSQNAyYM59AA).